# Simple Boolean Intersect issue Blender 2.82a

Tags: modifiers

Still very much a learner of Blender, although I have used some other 3D tools. I am trying to intersect a sphere with a cube so I selected the sphere in Object mode, went into edit mode and choose a boolean intersect modifier. In Edit mode (left pic) nothing appears to change (until I press "Apply") which is fair enough. In Object mode (right pic) I see the result but there appears to be an extraneous face left across the top of the remaining sphere. I cannot select that circle and delete it in either mode, whether or not I subsequently choose "Apply"  What have I missed? Thanks, John [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! My misunderstanding. I had to select the cube, add a difference boolean modifier, choose the sphere, press "Apply" and then remove the sphere myself to get the indent.